# What do I do to correct Error in `filter()` and then 'object not found'?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, filter

I'm trying to create a new data frame out of only specific rows from my existing data frame. First, I imported the dataset, and then I did this

```
read.csv("testvdemset.csv")
```

The code I'm using to create the new data frame is

```
data <- testvdemset %>%
```

- ```
  filter(country_name =='Argentina','Bolivia','Ecuador','Guatemala','Haiti','Honduras','Panama','Paraguay','Peru','Venezuela')
  ```

However, it returns this message

```
Error in `filter()`:
```

! Problem while computing `..2 = "Bolivia"`.
x Input `..2` must be a logical vector, not a character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Without changing anything, I'll run it again and get this

```
Error in filter(country_name == "Argentina", "Bolivia", "Ecuador", "Guatemala",  :
```

object 'country_name' not found

And that also happens when I do make changes. When I use exists() for country_name, it says that it does not exist, nor do any of the other variables (columns) in my existing data frame. I made sure that my working directory was correct and that there are no spelling/capitalization errors. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thank you!!

Comment: Try instead of `country_name == .....`, `country_name %in% c(...)`, if there is column `country_name` in your `testvdemset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data <- testvdemset %>% 
  filter(country_name %in% c('Argentina','Bolivia','Ecuador','Guatemala','Haiti','Honduras',
                         'Panama','Paraguay','Peru','Venezuela'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The package dplyr hasn't been installed or loaded into the library.

I used the following code and it worked for me:

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```